# Pluralization of martini

Tags: grammatical-number

Why is martini pluralized when a volume larger than one drink is referred to? "I have a pitcher if martinis chilling." We don't say we have a pitcher of lemonades chilling.

Comment: A martini is the cocktail, not the fluid. You wouldn't have a drop of martini, nor would you spill martini all over your shirt. Many cocktails (and other dishes) work this way, you have a pitcher of margaritas or Rob Roys. This isn't that strange, as the definition of the cocktail includes not only the liquid, but the manner of serving (up), the glass (eponymous), and the garnish options (go with the less-popular *lemon peel*).

Comment: Please add a checkable and reasonable source for 'I have a pitcher of martinis chilling'.